# 成语 for expressing that a couple was meant for eachother

Tags: word-requests, chengyu

I seem to recall there being a 成语 to the effect of, "Heaven brought them together," or something like that.  It expresses that the couple was truly meant for one another.  Do you know which 成语 I am thinking of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[佳偶天成](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/30316/) (a perfect couple that's made by heaven)

[天生一對](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/53096/) (born to be a perfect couple)

[天造地設](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/53097/) (a perfect couple created by heaven)

[天賜良緣](http://www.chengyu675.com/chengyudaquan/t/36980.html) (a perfect marriage that was grant by the Heaven )

The_Anomaly wrote:

> *...which of these are perhaps more commonly used than the others?*

佳偶天成, 天賜良緣, and 天作之合 are very literary phrases-- you usually find them in written form; and you only hear them commonly in wedding speeches.

天生一對 and 天造地設 can also be heard in wedding speeches, but they are more applicable in day-to-day conversations. They can describe something other than 'perfect couple'

- 天生一對 can refer to persons or things being extremely comparable or alike. For example: "你們倆一個是瘋子，一個是狂人, 真是天生一對." (one crazy, one mad; you two really are born to be a pair)
- 天造地設 can refer to persons or things being perfectly matched or perfectly suited in an arrangement. For example: "這是個天造地設的安排" (this is a perfect arrangement)

Comment: These are excellent, thank you.  Do you or @吳斯生 have any thoughts as to which of these are perhaps more commonly used than the others?  They all seem to really have an equivalent meaning.

Comment: 天生一对 is the most widely used one, and it can be used to any couple( for example, the 天賜良緣 usually refers to married couple)

Answer (score 3):

《汉语成语词典》

> 天作之合
>   tiān zuò zhī hé
>
> 【解释】好象是上天给予安排，很完美地配合到一起。祝人婚姻美满的话。
>
> 【出处】《诗经·大雅·大明》：“文王初载，天作之合。”
>
> 【用法】偏正式；作宾语、定语；含褒义，祝人婚姻美满的话
>
> 【英文】a heaven-made match; a union made by heaven; a match blessed by God